# Mirror incoming traffic on specific port to another IP, using my IPSec strongswan tunnel

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding, ipsec, strongswan, port-mirroring

I want to internally publish an SMTP server (IP 10.0.0.10) that is behind a VPN tunnel on my internal server (192.168.0.12) using `strongswan`. My `strongswan` is running within a docker container.

For this I want my internal server `192.168.0.12` to listen to its 25 port and to forward the traffic to the tunneled server on the same port `10.0.0.10:25`.

So far I tried using iptables, but without success.

`net.ipv4.ip_forward` is enabled on both the host and the docker container!

my `iptables-save` on `192.168.0.12` after strongswan is connected to the tunnel: (and yes I can ping the 10.0.0.10 from 192.168.0.12)

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Fri Jul 23 09:55:05 2021
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -s 10.0.0.0/16 -d 192.168.0.10/32 -i eth0 -m policy --dir in --pol ipsec --reqid 1 --proto esp -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -s 192.168.0.10/32 -d 10.0.0.0/16 -o eth0 -m policy --dir out --pol ipsec --reqid 1 --proto esp -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Jul 23 09:55:05 2021
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Fri Jul 23 09:55:05 2021
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2:1600]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [2:1600]
:DOCKER_OUTPUT - [0:0]
:DOCKER_POSTROUTING - [0:0]
-A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.11/32 -j DOCKER_OUTPUT
-A POSTROUTING -d 127.0.0.11/32 -j DOCKER_POSTROUTING
-A DOCKER_OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.11/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.11:45165
-A DOCKER_OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.11/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.11:53306
-A DOCKER_POSTROUTING -s 127.0.0.11/32 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 45165 -j SNAT --to-source :53
-A DOCKER_POSTROUTING -s 127.0.0.11/32 -p udp -m udp --sport 53306 -j SNAT --to-source :53
COMMIT
```

command `ip r` output:

```
default via 192.168.16.1 dev eth0
192.168.16.0/20 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.16.10 # this is a docker internal network for my services
192.168.0.10/30 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.12
```

I tried various commands like these:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 25 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.10:25
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 10.0.0.10 --dport 25 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.0.12
```

but without success.

I cannot provide any info on the `ip r` of the host nor the `iptables-save`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide the output of the following commands on *both the container host and the container*: `ip r` (and maybe also `ip a`), `iptables-save` and `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward`.

Comment: @TomYan added all information that I could gather, I am restricted on the host machine. I managed to ask the host whether IP forwarding was enabled, and it is enabled.

Comment: I don't understand. You don't have control over `my internal server (192.168.0.10)`? Or is it actually another container? (Running in parallel to the Strongswan one, which is `192.168.0.12`?)

Comment: Also the `ip r` output seems off as well. `192.168.0.12` isn't even a valid host address with `/30` (since it would be the subnet ID).

Comment: @TomYan thank you for your help, I updated the IPs so they are correct now. I don't have control over the host that is running the docker container. I only control the docker container itself `192.168.0.12`. I am sure the issue is not with the host, but with the `iptables` configuration inside the docker container.

Comment: The problem is, who / which host(s) will the server/container be serving / forwarding for? And how was this address on this `eth1` configured? DHCP? Static? (By you?) As I said, the output of `ip r` does not really make sense. Is it even a "real" paste? (Or is it some "write/type it down"?) And is this "docker internal network" (`eth0`) supposed to be irrelevant to your goal/clients here?

Comment: Also, if this server/forwarder here is the same container as the strongswan one, where's even the route to the tunnel? Have you configured policy routing or what?

Comment: How do you test this? By connecting to port 25 of the host? Or from another container? Either way, do these packets actually enter the container and hit the NAT rules?

Comment: @ecdsa I test this with `telnet 10.0.0.10 25` on the `strongswan container` and the goal is to `telnet strongswan 25` assuming that the container name is `strongswan`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue using `traefik`.

I installed traefik on the host (`192.168.0.12`) that has the `strongswan tunnel` and used a `TCP router` to forward all traffic to the tunnel.

`traefik` installation:

```
wget -O /traefik.tar.gz https://github.com/traefik/traefik/releases/download/v2.4.12/traefik_v2.4.12_linux_amd64.tar.gz \
    && tar -zxvf /traefik.tar.gz \
    && ln -s /traefik /usr/bin/traefik
```

`traefik.yaml`:

```
entryPoints:
  smtp:
    address: ":1025"

accessLog: {}

providers:
  file:
    directory: /traefik-conf/dynamic/
    watch: true

api:
  dashboard: true
  insecure: true
```

my `/traefik-conf/dynamic/dynamic.yaml`:

```
tcp:
  routers:
    smtp-router:
      rule: "HostSNI(`*`)"
      entryPoints:
        - smtp
      service: smtp-service

  services:
    smtp-service:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - address: 10.0.0.10:25
```

Run `traefik` (I don't know how to properly run it as a background daemon):

```
traefik --configfile /traefik-conf/traefik.yml &
```

Now I can connect to the tunneled `smtp server` from everywhere inside my network using `192.168.0.12:1025`.

I created an example using docker over [here on github](https://github.com/tgerakitis/docker-ipsec-tunnel)